# Selenium : googlemap markers dont appear in my xpath elements?

Tags: javascript, selenium, inspect

I would like to scrape some informations from a googlemap applet.

The page is here : http://www.annuaire-des-psychologues.fr/psychologue/limousin/
You can click on the map on items to get informations displayed over the map.

In normal googlemap i can find the marker elements, but on the link i provided, i dont see the markers on the map in my dev inspector. If i click a marker, then i see the dialog box that appeared in the elements in the dev inspector.

When i try to inspect with developers tools, i dont see anything...ie: i dont see the markers elements in my developer tool. If i click a marker, some new elements appear in my developer tool but i would like to automate the clicks on the marker with selenium.

I guess it's javascript or something like that. How can i manage to retrieve the elements xpaths?

If it is javascript, do you have documentation on how to retrieve it in selenium and how to spot the source javascript used in the page im trying to scrape?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What element are you trying to grab? you can use xpath for this

```
element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="(//*[src()='ur_element_here'])")
```

when you try to inspect and click a certain location on the map it'll link you to

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="ur_element_here"></script>
```

you are basically telling it to search via the src header and find whatever text comes after it

Comment: I would like to automate the click: i would like to find the xpath of each element on the map. I dont see anything in the inspector regarding theses elements

Comment: to be more precise: in normal googlemap i can find the marker elements, but on the link i provided, i dont see the markers on the map in my dev inspector. If i click a marker, then i see the dialog box that appeared in the elements in the dev inspector.

Comment: when i hover on the map markers, there is a one big div element but no markers elements...i dont know how to do